# Как сделать ссылками элементы раскрывающегося списка?

Tags: html

У меня есть html код, в котором я создаю выпадающий список с несколькими ссылками:

```
<select>
    <option><a href="localhost:8080">Бел</a></option>
    <option><a href="localhost:8080/ru">Рус</a></option>
    <option><a href="localhost:8080/ua">Укр</a></option>
    <option><a href="localhost:8080/eng">Eng</a></option>
</select>
```

Однако эти ссылки не кликабельны, то есть по нажатию не происходит перенаправление на другую страницу. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью JS вы можете при изменении значения value у select отправлять пользователя на другую страницу

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');

select.addEventListener('change', function(){
  window.location.href = select.value
})
```

```html
<select class="select">
    <option value="localhost:8080">Бел</option>
    <option value="localhost:8080/ru">Рус</option>
    <option value="localhost:8080/ua">Укр</option>
    <option value="localhost:8080/eng">Eng</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action=''>
<select name='menu'>

<option selected value='/ua/'>Украина</option>
<option value='/ru/'>Россия</option>

</select>
<input type=button value='Ok' onclick='top.location.href=this.form. menu.options[this.form.menu.selectedIndex].value'>
</form>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Элементы внутри select тега не могут содержать интерактивных элементов, в том числе и ссылки. Если вам нужен выпадающий список с ссылками, чистым html не обойтись. Только добавлять css стиль и js скрипты.